# Why can't I use Bean that I have created before?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a pretty simple class and just want to create @Bean and inject it in the method. But when I use passwordEncoder - it can't find an instance of it. Same for daoAuthenticationProvider ( daoAuthenticationProvider bean uses passwordEncoder bean ).

```
 @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable();
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10);
    }
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        daoProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        return daoProvider;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no field `passwordEncoder` so how should it be found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a compilation issue not a Spring problem. You would need to either have an instance named `passwordEncoder` or inject it by invoking the method `passwordEncoder()` as follows:

```
@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
    [...]
    daoProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    [...]
}
```